# Django Views---can't see the URL correctly

Tags: django

Inside an app called batches, I have set different url patterns. I have now 3 urls for batches, individuals and business names. It seems that when goind to the last 2 i am seeying only the info from batches all the time. Inside my app-batches i have 3 tables/classes.

Please see my url pattern of the website:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^batches/', include('batches.urls')),
    url(r'^screenings/', include('screenings.urls')),
    url(r'^individuals/', include('batches.urls')),
    url(r'^businessnames', include('batches.urls')),
]
```

This is what i have in my viewes:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .models import BusinessName
from .models import Individuals
from .models import Batches

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    all_Batches = Batches.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for batch in all_Batches:
        url = '/batches/' + str(batch.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="#"' + url + '">' + str(batch.FileName)+ '</a><br>'
    return  HttpResponse(html)

def detail(request, batches_id):  #parametrul asta batches_id tr sa se gaseasca in urls.py din app
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Batches ID:"  + str(batches_id) + "</h2")


def index_businessname(request):
    all_BusinessNames = BusinessName.objects.all()
    html1 = ''
    for bn in all_BusinessNames:
        url = '/businessnames/' + str(bn.id) + '/'
        html1 += '<a href="#"' + url + '">' + bn.FullName + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html1)

def detail_businessname(request, businessname_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Business Names ID:"  + str(businessname_id) + "</h2")

def index_individual(request):
    all_individuals = Individuals.objects.all()
    html2 = ''
    for i in all_individuals:
        url = '/individuals/' + i.id + '/'
        html2 += '<a href="#"' + url + '">' + i.FullName + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html2)


def detail_individual(request, individuals_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Individual Names ID:"  + str(individuals_id)+ "</h2")
```

This is what i have in my app urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # /batches/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # /batches/2
    url(r'^(?P<batches_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail, name="detail"),

    # businessname/1
    url(r'^$',views.index_businessname, name="index_businessname"),
    # businessname/1
    url(r'^(?P<businessname_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail_businessname, name="detail_businessname"),


    # individuals/1
    url(r'^$', views.index_individual, name="index_individuals"),
    # individuals/1
    url(r'^(?P<individuals_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail_individual, name="detail_individual"),
]
```

If someone could help me, i would owe you a lot. I read the documentation, but i am stuck in it.

Thank you,
Cohen

Comment: How are you expecting Django to know the difference between a request for a batch and a request for a business? The URL patterns are exactly the same.

Comment: ok thank you! how i can change this?

Comment: better to separate URL files , create 3 separate URL files for batches, individuals and business in app folder and redirect the URL from url.py file to specific files, it will help you in future if you want to append functionalities in specific files

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are defining three end points for the same urls. Django searches the pattern from top to bottom and return what matches first. So, it doesn't know which of them are you specified unless you explicitly tell it. So, it'd be better to define the prefixes for end points of the urls in an app, in the same app itself.

You may define the endpoints like this in your main `urls.py`,

```
url(r'^batches/', include('batches.urls')),
```

then, in your `app.urls.py` change them accordingly,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^/(?P<batches_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail, name="detail"),
    url(r'^businessname/$',views.index_businessname, name="index_businessname"),
    url(r'^businessname/(?P<businessname_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail_businessname, name="detail_businessname"),
    url(r'^individuals/$', views.index_individual, name="index_individuals"),
    url(r'^individuals/(?P<individuals_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail_individual, name="detail_individual"),
]
```

Comment: Thank you zaidfazil for your answer! so you suggest to change my website's url pattern for these 2: url(r'^individuals/', include('individuals.urls')),
    url(r'^businessnames', include('businessnames.urls')),

Comment: No, keep `url(r'^', include('batches.urls')),`, then remove all the duplicates (ie, which contains `include('batches.urls')` ) in your main `urls.py`. Then change the patterns like in my answer in `batches.urls.py`.

Comment: Hi zaidfazil, i changed the url pattern. What i have to do more? to change the 2 url like this==>  url(r'^individuals/'),
    url(r'^businessnames/'),

Comment: Does your urlpattern of your website look like this now??

`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('batches.urls')),
    url(r'^screenings/', include('screenings.urls')),
]`

Remove the lines with `businessnames` and `individuals` in it. Have you got it?

Comment: Zaidfazil, you rock! thank you very much for your comments! You really helped me.  I have still a question. Now i can get them displayed properly, but when i click on the names, i am not redirected to the detail page. Is this something i made wrong? Thank you for all your comments!

Comment: For that you need to add a hyperlink to that element in the template with a parameter, something like `<a href="{% url 'detail_individual' item.pk %}">`, something like this.

Comment: Hi, i did some testings and it seems that now i can see the individuals and business names, but not the batches. ---The current path, batches/, didn't match any of these.------Thank you!

Comment: You have to go to url `localhost:8000/batches/` for that.

Comment: Hi, i did that, and i was not able to see that path...---The current path, batches/, didn't match any of these.------Thank you!

Comment: hi, i have this error: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/batches/
The current path, batches/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: My main urls are now only 3: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^batches/', include('batches.urls')),
    url(r'^screenings/', include('screenings.urls')),


]

Comment: is working: http://127.0.0.1:8000/batches/individuals/.      and http://127.0.0.1:8000/batches/businessnames/#.            but not http://127.0.0.1:8000/batches/

Comment: lol, it got displayed on the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/batches/batches